# Random queries of grammar generated using PLY

Tags: random, ply

I have created a grammar using PLY and I would like to generate some random queries that follow this grammar. Is there any way of doing this? I could't find anything in this matter only for context free grammars.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The grammar used in PLY *is* a context-free grammar.

Comment: @Sneftel OK, but all I found included defining the grammar differently than PLY e.g. http://www.decontextualize.com/teaching/rwet/recursion-and-context-free-grammars/.